# Fragmented stress of feminine nouns

Tags: ударение

Recently I've found a few feminine nouns, whose declension follows the following pattern:

- Singular/Plural
- N./A. но́вость; но́вости
- G. но́вости; новос**те́й**
- D. но́вости; новос**тя́м**
- I. но́востью; новос**тя́ми**
- P. но́вости; новос**тя́х**

When I came across the stress pattern of **новость**, I thought all nouns ending in -ость followed the same pattern, but I was wrong, and apparently this fragmented pattern (stressed stem on singular and *nominative plural*, stressed ending on the remaining cases) is not that frequent.

I got to know two more nouns following this pattern:

- це́рковь (це́ркви, церкве́й, церква́м);
- дере́вня (дере́вни, дереве́нь, деревня́м);

Are there any other frequently used feminine nouns with such pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Obsolete word **сени** and semi-obsolete **ясли** (which both only have plural form) so not frequent, then **сани**, **люди** (both of which only exist in plural), **часть**, **мать**, **дочь**, **смерть**, **соль**, **горсть**, **кость**, **сеть**, **тень**, **дверь** (all last three with variable stress in sing. P./L. + in sing. G. & D. of *дверь*), **полость**, **плоскость**, **скорость**, **область**, **камень**, **зверь**

Save for the last two seems mainly typical of words of the 3d declension group.

And of course the most frequent - **блядь**, which however as an expletive very rarely gets to be inflected.

Comment: Сени и ясли - obsolete? No, not yet.

Comment: i of course am no criterion for anything but being an urban resident i since about 30 years ago don't remember myself having used these words in my daily conversations, overheard them used in conversations of other people or encountered them in a text written in the last couple of decades which deals with mundane matters

Comment: My opinion is also based just on my own experience. `Ясли` is still used in "bureaucratic context" as official name for "kindergarden for children below 3 years", while most of parents prefer "детский сад". `Сени` is a specific part of a typical village house, it is not the same as `прихожая`. Typical city apartment have no it, so the word is not used. But people, who still live in countryside, still has `сени` as a part of a house and use this word.

Comment: that's why i labeled *ясли* as semi-obsolete, one meaning is lost and the word is in use due to its second meaning being still extant

Answer (score 1):

See

- [Russian 3rd-declension feminine-form accent-e nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_3rd-declension_feminine-form_accent-e_nouns)
- [Russian nouns with accent pattern e](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_nouns_with_accent_pattern_e).

Comment: and generally [6 Russian stress patterns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Russian_stress_patterns_-_nouns)